# ASCII sum of all the all the characters in column Mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, ascii

I have a table users but i have shown only 2 columns I want to sum all the characters of name column.

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  0 | user  |
|  1 | admin |
|  3 | edit  |
+----+-------+
```

for example ascii sum of user will be 
sum(user)=117+115+101+114=447

i have tired this

```
SELECT ASCII(Substr(name, 1,1)) + ASCII(Substr(name, 2, 1)) FROM user
```

but it only sums 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to fetch one character at a time to do the sum.  One method is to write a function with a while loop.  You can do this with a `SELECT`, if you know the longest string:

```
SELECT name, SUM(ASCII(SUBSTR(name, n, 1)))
FROM user u JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 -- sufficient for your examples
     ) n
     ON LENGTH(name) <= n.n
GROUP BY name;
```

If your goal is to turn the string as something that can be easily compared or a fixed length, then you might consider the [encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) in MySQL.  Adding up the ASCII values is not a particularly good hash function (because strings with the same characters in different orders produce the same value).  At the very least, multiplying each ASCII value by the position is a bit better.

Comment: thanks it works. i am bit new do i need to store it as procedure. and it will be good if u also mention multiply each ascii that will be great